# How to connect Entity Framework 6 with SQLite database

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, entity-framework, database-connection, sqlite-net

Facing Some Issues to connect Entity Framework 6 with SQLite database can someone help please

Comment: Some tips here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Comment: In order to solve the problem more quickly and accurately, please provide detailed information about some of the problems you encountered.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.